# How to check geometry type from geo_types

Tags: rust, geometry, borrow-checker

I'm new to Rust and I'm still struggling with the borrowing concept in combination with the [TryFrom](https://docs.rs/geo-types/latest/geo_types/geometry/struct.Point.html#impl-TryFrom%3CGeometry%3CT%3E%3E-for-Point%3CT%3E) function from the `geo_types` crate.

I basically want to do different things depending on the actual `Geometry` type:

```
use geo_types::{Geometry, Point, LineString};

fn some_func(g : Geometry<f64>) {
    if let Ok(p) = Point::try_from(g) {
        print!("POINT");
    } else if let Ok(ls) = LineString::try_from(g) { 
        print!("LINESTRING");
    } else {
        print!("UNKNOWN");
    }
}
```

but this fails with:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `g`
 --> src/main.rs:7:49
  |
4 | fn some_func(g : Geometry<f64>) {
  |              - move occurs because `g` has type `Geometry`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
5 |     if let Ok(p) = Point::try_from(g) {
  |                                    - value moved here
6 |         print!("POINT");
7 |     } else if let Ok(ls) = LineString::try_from(g) { 
  |                                                 ^ value used here after move
  |
help: consider cloning the value if the performance cost is acceptable
  |
5 |     if let Ok(p) = Point::try_from(g.clone()) {
  |                                     ++++++++
```

So I was changing the function to take a geometry refernce:

```
fn some_func(g : &Geometry<f64>)
```

but that fails with:

> the trait `From<&Geometry>` is not implemented for `geo_types::Point<_>`

Next thing I tried is to de-reference the geometry:

```
Point::try_from(*g)
```

but this also fails with:

> cannot move out of `*g` which is behind a shared reference
> move occurs because `*g` has type `Geometry`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

So what can I do to get this code working or how can I do this differently?

Comment: In case the compiler has some suggestion I recommend evaluating what it suggests, in this case it would work, wouldn't it? I.e. "consider cloning the value" with `g.clone()` in place of the first `g` of your originial attempt.

Comment: @cafce25 Forgot to mention, but cloning would be an unnecessary waste that I would like to avoid, especially b/c I would need to clone the whole geometry object (which could be quite huge) in every if branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [Geometry](https://docs.rs/geo-types/latest/geo_types/geometry/enum.Geometry.html) is an enum, so you should use pattern matching to check which variant you are using.

```rust
pub enum Geometry<T: CoordNum = f64> {
    Point(Point<T>),
    Line(Line<T>),
    LineString(LineString<T>),
    Polygon(Polygon<T>),
    MultiPoint(MultiPoint<T>),
    MultiLineString(MultiLineString<T>),
    MultiPolygon(MultiPolygon<T>),
    GeometryCollection(GeometryCollection<T>),
    Rect(Rect<T>),
    Triangle(Triangle<T>),
}
```

So you can rewrite your function as follows:

```rust
use geo_types::{Geometry, Point, LineString};

fn some_func(g : Geometry<f64>) {
    match g {
        Geometry::Point(_) => print!("POINT"),
        Geometry::LineString(_) => print!("LINESTRING"),
        // It's not really unknown, because there are other enum variants,
        // but I left it to not change your original (intended?) bahavior.
        _ -> print!("UNKNOWN")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked like a charm. I feel I have to read more about enums in Rust b/c coming from a C++ background those are quite different than the C++ ones (they are actually comparable to a flat class hirachrchy with one base and several derived classes)

Comment: Then give a read to The Rust Book [chapter on enums](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-00-enums.html). Enums like in rust are sometimes called "algebraic data types" or "sum types". They are _kind of_ similar to c++'s `std::variant`, although without _pattern matching_ std::variant is massively inferior to proper language support. If you are interested how they are implemented under the hood look at C's "tagged unions".